# Must the domain of a CDF be $\mathbb{R}$ or can it also be a strict subset?

Tags: probability, distributions, cumulative-distribution-function

So my question is whether the domain of a cumulative distribution function has to be $\mathbb{R}$ or whether it can also be a strict subset. The reason I'm asking is because I'm currently going through the book *Statistical Inference* by Casella and Berger, and while Definition 1.5.1 would suggest it has to be $\mathbb{R}$, in Exercise 1.47 d) they then ask the reader to prove that the function

$$1-e^{-x} \text{, }x \in (0, \infty)$$

is also a CDF.

Comment: What would you make of an amended definition which stated $0, x \le 0$?

Comment: I believe the convention C&B are following is that certain functions defined on a subset of $\mathbb R$ can be continued *uniquely* to CDFs on $\mathbb R.$ That's obviously the case here, where the continuation value must equal $0$ for $x\in(-\infty,0].$

Comment: No. See, e.g., the [triangular distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution).

Comment: @whuber, yeah, that makes sense. I know this can be done, it's just that they left it as I wrote above, so I wasn't sure whether we can change the limit requirement to $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}$. Correct me if I'm wrong, but from your answer it then seems that no, you can't do that, and instead you must extend the function so that its domain is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @corey979 To what statement are you replying "no"?  The triangular distribution you point to is no exception to the convention I described.  Its CDF, as an entire function of $\mathbb R,$ is completely determined by the definition on the interval $[a,b].$  Please note that the "support" referenced on the Wikipedia page is not the same as the domain of the CDF.  Ryker: exactly what is this "limit requirement" to which you refer?

Comment: @whuber, that you need to look at $\lim_{x \to -\infty} F_X(x)$ and verify it's equal to $0$.

Comment: @Ryker: why would you be concerned with limits at minus infinity if you can simply define the CDF to be zero on the negative half axis?

Comment: @StephanKolassa, right, I get that, but the authors specifically mention the limit at minus infinity, so I wanted to clarify if that's necessary or not. I get that you can extend a cdf, but my question was whether that's needed at all or if you can just have its domain be a subset of the real numbers without the need for such an extension.

Comment: @whuber I guess I misunderstood the question. Maybe the [log-normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) is a better illustration? 'Cause its CDF is dependent on $\ln x$, and in this case we cannot just say that it's $=0$ for $x\leq 0$, so its support is $(0,\infty)$, isn't it?

Comment: Like all CDFs, that of the lognormal distribution depends directly on $x,$ @corey979.  The statement "its support is $(0,\infty)$" implies the CDF is zero for all $x\le 0.$